# Angle between velocity vector and radial line is constant implies curve is an spiral.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves, plane-curves

Suppose that a curve $\alpha(t)$ is such that the angle $\phi$ between $\alpha'(t)$ and radial line is constant (and distinct from $\pi/2$) then show that $\alpha(t)=(ae^{bt}\cos(t),ae^{bt}\sin(t))$.

I've already proven the following equality for parametric curves:

$$\tan(\phi)=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}x-y}{x+\frac{dy}{dx}y}$$ where $\frac{dy}{dx}:=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$

Supposing that $\tan(\phi)$ is a constant I  tried to solve the differential equation but I got stuck.

I'm aware that the system is easier in polar coordinates but I'd like to see if there is a solution for this approach.

Comment: I don't think you want to exclude $\phi=\pi/2$ (what you get when $b=0$), but $0$ or $\pi$.  Anyway, the denominator shouldn't be $1+y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ but $x+y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, so you have a [homogeneous (degree-zero) first-order DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_first-order_differential_equations).

Comment: You're right it was a typo, could you expand on the DE ?

Comment: You get a logarithmic spiral from the given conditions, but the exact parameterization would depend on the magnitude of $\alpha'(t)$ at each $t,$ wouldn't it? I think it's accurate to say that $\alpha(t)=(ae^{b\theta(t)}\cos(\theta(t)),ae^{b\theta(t)}\sin(\theta(t)))$ for some suitable function $\theta(t)$ but technically not accurate to say that necessarily $\alpha(t)=(ae^{bt}\cos(t),ae^{bt}\sin(t)).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the tangent line is not radial (so $\tan(\frac\pi2+\phi)\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant $k$)
$$
x+y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=k\left(y-x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)
$$
or equivalently
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{k y-x}{kx+y}.
$$
The RHS is homogeneous degree $0$ (i.e., scaling $(x,y)\mapsto(\lambda x,\lambda y)$ leaves the RHS unchanged for all $\lambda$), and we know the method to solve this class of equations is to let $y=zx$ and get
$$
z+x\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{k z-1}{k+z}
$$
which rearranges to
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}(\log x)}{\mathrm{d}z}=
\frac1x\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{z+k}{k z-1-z(z+k)}=-\frac{z+k}{1+z^2}.
$$
Integrating gives $x=F(z)$ and hence you can express the solution either as a parametric curve $(x,y)(z)=(F(z),zF(z))$, or as an implicit curve $x=F(y/x)$.

---

N.B. Of course this only solve it away from points on the $y$-axis, but you could use $y$ instead of $x$ as the local parameter for the curve for points on the $y$-axis and let $x(y)=ys(y)$ for unknown function $s$, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=k(x+y\frac{dy}{dx})$?

Comment: @SebastianCor No, I want $-\frac1k=\tan\phi$.

Comment: How would you derive the first equation then?

Comment: You have $-\frac1k=\tan\phi=\frac{xy'-y}{x+yy'}$ so multiplying both sides by $-k(x+yy')$ gives $x+yy'=k(y-xy')$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, but the integral gives me the function $x(z)=A\sqrt{z^2+1}e^{-k\tan^{-1}(z)}$ how do I show that it is a logarithmic spiral?

Comment: You should have $x(z)=\frac1{\sqrt{z^2+1}}e^{-k\tan^{-1}z}$ (up to multiplicative constant).  So letting $z=\tan t$ gets $x(t)=a\cos(t) e^{-kt}$.

Comment: You're right I missed the minus sign.